# How to show Toast Message with Binding Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I dont see Toast Messages. I want to show a toast messagges when click userAddFavoriteButton..

```
@BindingAdapter("addFavorite")
fun bindAddFavorite(userAddFavoriteButton: ImageView, login : String?){
 userAddFavoriteButton.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(it.context, login,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
 }
}
```

**XML**

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userAddFavoriteButton"
      ...
        app:addFavorite="@{user.login}"
        ... />
```

Comment: where do you call `bindAddFavorite`? Is it `onCreate`?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I edit my code. I use in xml

Answer (score 0):

```
@BindingAdapter("addFavorite")
fun bindAddFavorite(userAddFavoriteButton: ImageView, login : String?,context:Context){
 userAddFavoriteButton.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(context, login,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you going to call this function from another activity?

Comment: I don't give direct context. fun bindAddFavorite(userAddFavoriteButton: ImageView, login : String?,context:Context) <--

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using binding adapter you can import the toast class and use it on click of the view.

```
    <data>
       ...
      <import type="android.widget.Toast"/>
       ...
     </data>
       ...
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userAddFavoriteButton"
          ...
          
android:onClick="@{(view)->Toast.makeText(context,user.login,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}"
            ... />
```